# How to load all dependency of urijs by rquirejs config?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bower

I want to include this library for use https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/tree/master

I have added it to `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
       "urijs": "~1.16.1"
 }
 ...
}
```

When I load my project in a browser, I got these error:

[image]

These scripts are all part of the urijs project. You can find them here: https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/tree/master/src

I would like to be able to resolve by requirejs configuration alone with minimal change (i.e. hopefully do not need to specify each dependent script indiviudally). What is the easiest way to define the dependency?

Is it possible? If so, how?

At the end I can resolve it by creating the final artefact and hosted the outcome in a forked project. I am hoping for a more elegant and/or simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like URI.js sets up a universal module loader that should work with RequireJS.  It doesn't look like you have to reference every script in your config.  Make your RequireJS config file look like their readme.md:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    urijs: 'where-you-put-uri.js/src'
  }
});

require(['urijs/URI'], function(URI) {
  console.log("URI.js and dependencies: ", URI("//amazon.co.uk").is('sld') ? 'loaded' : 'failed');
});
require(['urijs/URITemplate'], function(URITemplate) {
  console.log("URITemplate.js and dependencies: ", URITemplate._cache ? 'loaded' : 'failed');
});
```